# T-SQL variable counter not incrementing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to increment counter and update rows in my db table, but some reason it is not incrementing.
Can anyone see what's wrong with this T-SQL?

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR
declare @counter int
    set @counter = 0
SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT ShipmentTrackingNumber,
       Courier
FROM   Shipping WHERE (ShipmentTrackingNumber = '')
OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @id, @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE SHipping SET ShipmentTrackingNumber = 'STN00000' + cast(@counter as VARCHAR(16))
    set @counter = @counter + 1
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @id, @name
END
CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Comment: You can do this with row_number as a single update statement instead of looping. Not to mention that your update statement currently is updating the entire table each iteration through the loop. I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: Never go full rbar...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not that the `@counter` is not incrementing.  Your problem is that the `update` is updating *all* the rows in each iteration.  There is no `where` clause, so every row ends up with the same value.

I suspect your intention is an updatable cursor, but that is not what you have written.

What you really want is this much simpler version:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from shipping s
      where ShipmentTrackingNumber = ''
     )
update toupdate
    set ShipmentTrackingNumber = 'STN00000' + cast(seqnum as varchar(16));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mantioned so, I am assuming that Your Primary Key field is ID.

The following query will get the latest `ShipmentTrackingNumber` number so we can continue the increment process after that number.

```
DECLARE @Last_ID INT;
SELECT @Last_ID = MAX(T.STN) FROM (SELECT RIGHT(ShipmentTrackingNumber,LEN(ShipmentTrackingNumber) - 3) AS STN 
                       FROM SHipping WHERE ShipmentTrackingNumber <> '') T
```

I have after that, we are executing Update statement to update the `ShipmentTrackingNumber` field

```
Update SH
SET    ShipmentTrackingNumber = 'STN' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(SH1.ROW_ID AS VARCHAR(6)) ,6)
FROM   SHipping SH INNER JOIN (SELECT  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) + @Last_ID) AS ROW_ID,ID
                               FROM    SHipping SH1
                               WHERE   ISNULL(SH1.ShipmentTrackingNumber,'') = ''
                              ) SH1  ON SH1.ID=SH.ID
```

Here I have use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the serial number in accending order and added a latest `ShipmentTrackingNumber` number in it. So, we can get the next tracking number.

There is another thing I have notice that your `ShipmentTrackingNumber` has some prefix like 5 times zero before number (ie. `STN000001`). So, I would suggest you to use fix the number of digits in your tracking number if the values increased in multiple digits (i.e. `STN000011`, `STN005210`, `STN325210`) by removing unnecessary Zeros using `Right()` function.

**It will help you to get the correct sorting order.**